# A nondeterministic covariance-stationary process approximated by an ARMA process

Tags: time-series, arima, stochastic-processes, approximation

We know that the Wold Decomposition Theorem says that any purely nondeterministic covariance-stationary process, $x = [x_t : t \in \mathbb{Z}]$, can be written as a linear combination of lagged values of a white noise process:

$$x_t = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\psi_j u_{t-j}$$

According to this lesson [lesson](http://www.phdeconomics.sssup.it/documents/Lesson11.pdf) (slides 12-14),  under general conditions, the infinite lag polynomial of the Wold decomposition can be approximated by the ratio of two finite-lag polynomials:

$$\psi(L) \approx \frac{\theta(L)}{\phi(L)}$$

in other words, the process $x$ can be accurately approximated by a ARMA process in the following sense:
$$x_t^* = \frac{\theta(L)}{\phi(L)} u_t $$

I would like to understand better this approximation.

1. What general conditions are these?
2. Is this approach via sequences of ARMA processes?
3. Does the approximation use any metric?
4. How can we determine the $\phi(L)$ and $\theta(L)$ polynomials? Are they unique?

Do you have some reference (book, paper etc) or insight?